# What is the difference between express-ejs-layouts and DHTML?

Tags: html, express, ejs, dhtml

Google search told me that DHTML means generating HTML content dynamically. The examples were using Javascript for the dynamic content.

EJS says the same about itself. E stands for Embedded but that's what DHTML does already - embedds Javascript?

- Does EJS have some extra features which DHTML doesn't?
- Is EJS a framework on the top of DHTML like Qt is for C++?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between express-ejs-layouts and DHTML?

`express-ejs-layouts` is an extension of `ejs` that allows server side layouts with `ejs` templates. DHTML is a general term for extending HTML with client side JS (with or without templates). Both approaches are dynamic. Some modern frameworks like React support server side rendering, which essentially implements both client and server side templating with the same code.

> E stands for Embedded but that's what DHTML does already - embedds Javascript?

`ejs` is just the name chosen for that specific technology, and DHTML doesn't necessarily have to have JS in HTML files.

> Does EJS have some extra features which DHTML doesn't?

EJS templates can run on the server and generate head tags, which isn't always possible for DHTML templates.

> Is EJS a framework on the top of DHTML like Qt is for C++?

No. It would be more accurate to describe EJS as a templating technology, and DHTML as a frontend architecture. EJS could be part of a DHTML separate, or separate (on the server only).